# Does clang have an equivalent of GCC's -mno-vzeroupper flag?

Tags: gcc, clang, avx

The title says it all!
Does clang have an equivalent of GCC's -mno-vzeroupper flag?
I use 3.5, perhaps it will be in 3.6 ?

Comment: Funny. One can use `-mllvm -x86-use-vzeroupper` but I don't know how to negate that. There is a pass called `x86-vzeroupper` but I can't find an option to disable a pass... If you are willing to patch the sources and rebuild llvm, it will be trivial.

Comment: I believe it would be a good idea to file a PR in llvm's bugzilla: http://llvm.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi . They don't seem opposed to adding such a switch: http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2013-September/065761.html

Comment: Two years later... any update on this ?

Comment: No, the vzeroupper instructions are still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:
`clang++ -mllvm -x86-use-vzeroupper=0`