# What is the /d2vzeroupper MSVC compiler optimization flag doing?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, avx, compiler-flags, amd-processor

What is the `/d2vzeroupper` MSVC compiler optimization flag doing?

I was reading through this Compiler Options Quick Reference Guide
for Epyc CPUs from AMD: https://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2020/04/Compiler%20Options%20Quick%20Ref%20Guide%20for%20AMD%20EPYC%207xx2%20Series%20Processors.pdf

For MSVC, to "Optimize for 64-bit AMD processors", they recommend to enable `/favor:AMD64 /d2vzeroupper`.

What `/favor:AMD64` is doing is clear, there is documentation about that in the MSVC docs. But I can't seem to find `/d2vzeroupper` being mentioned anywhere in the internet at all, no documentation anywhere. What is it doing?

Comment: There appears to be some info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303780/why-is-this-sse-code-6-times-slower-without-vzeroupper-on-skylake).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: When using `/favor:AMD64` add `/d2vzeroupper` to avoid very poor performance of SSE code on both current AMD CPUs and Intel CPUs.

---

Generally `/d1...` and `/d2...` are "secret" (undocumented) MSVC options to tune compiler behavior. `/d1...` apply to complier front-end, `/d2...` apply to compiler back-end.

---

**`/d2vzeroupper` enables compiler-generated `vzeroupper` instruction**

See [Do I need to use _mm256_zeroupper in 2021?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68736527/2945027) for more information.

Normally it is by default. You can disable it by `/d2vzeroupper-`. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/P48crzTrb

`/favor:AMD64` switch suppresses `vzeroupper`, so `/d2vzeroupper` enables it back.

The up-to-date Visual Studio 2022 has fixed that, so `/favor:AMD64` still emits `vzeroupper` and `/d2vzeroupper` is not needed to enable it.

---

Reason: current AMD optimization guides (available from [AMD site](https://developer.amd.com/resources/developer-guides-manuals/); direct [pdf](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/56665.zip) link) suggest:

> #### 2.11.6 Mixing AVX and SSE
>
> There is a significant penalty for mixing SSE and AVX instructions when the upper 128 bits of the
> YMM registers contain non-zero data. Transitioning in either direction will cause a micro-fault to
> spill or fill the upper 128 bits of all 16 YMM registers. There will be an approximately 100 cycle
> penalty to signal and handle this fault. To avoid this penalty, a VZEROUPPER or VZEROALL
> instruction should be used to clear the upper 128 bits of all YMM registers when transitioning from
> AVX code to SSE or unknown code

Older AMD processor did not need `vzeroupper`, so `/favor:AMD64` implemented optimization for them, even though penalizing Intel CPUs. From [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/favor-optimize-for-architecture-specifics?view=msvc-160):

> **/favor:AMD64**
>
> (x64 only) optimizes the generated code for the AMD Opteron, and Athlon processors that support 64-bit extensions. The optimized code can run on all x64 compatible platforms. Code that is generated by using /favor:AMD64 might cause worse performance on Intel processors that support Intel64.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Do you know how it makes sense that AMD recommends to manually specify /d2vzeroupper on MSVC if it's enabled by default anyways? That seems a bit weird. Are you sure that not adding /d2vzeroupper has the exact same effect as adding /d2vzeroupper, on all code?

Comment: @JohnAl I've experimented a bit more and edited my answer. Now it should make sense

Comment: @JohnAl: `/favor:AMD64` is an overall tuning option (like `gcc -mtune=znver1`) that presumably has many more effects, like setting values for inlining and loop unrolling decision heuristics.  AMD CPUs (up to and including at least Zen 1; IDK how Zen2 handles things now that it has full 256-bit wide SIMD register entries and execution units) don't have SSE/AVX transition penalties and thus don't need vzeroupper for performance reasons.  But without `vzeroupper`, your code could run *very* poorly on Intel CPUs so AMD might be suggesting that to make binaries that are generally usable.

Comment: @JohnAl: Or maybe that's a sign that current AMD CPUs *do* need `vzeroupper` to avoid SSE/AVX transition penalties, like Intel CPUs with AVX.

Comment: @PeterCordes, the later is true. I've edited my answer to quote _Software Optimization
Guide for AMD EPYC™ 7003 Processors_

Comment: @JohnAl as it is now clear that the recommendation is right for the current AMD, I've created Dev Com issue to make `/favor:AMD64` not skipping `vzeroupper` https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/favor:AMD64-should-emit-vzeroupper-for/1539224